# how to filter elements from a list based on index divisble by an integer in r?

Tags: r

I am new in R & trying to **select elements from a list based on index divisible by 6**.

let's suppose list is `mypics` and its content is:
`"b1.jpg", "b2.jpg", "b3.jpg", "b4.jpg", "b5.jpg", "b6.jpg", "c1.jpg", "c2.jpg", "c3.jpg", "c4.jpg", "c5.jpg", "c6.jpg", "p1.jpg", "p2.jpg", "p3.jpg", "p4.jpg", "p5.jpg", "p6.jpg"`

Now I want to select all the elements except the one's divisible by 6 and I have tried below code but its not working.

```
mypics[for (i in 1:length(mypics) ) {(!i %% 6 == 0){return (i)}} ]
```

whereas below partial test code works:

```
for (i in 1:length(mypics)){
  if (! i %% 6 == 0) {
  print(i)
  }
} 

################# output #################
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
[1] 11
[1] 13
[1] 14
[1] 15
[1] 16
[1] 17
```

I am not sure if I am not returning it correctly or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop here. Try :

```
mypics <- mypics[seq_along(mypics) %% 6 != 0]
```

Or using recycling technique :

```
mypics <- mypics[c(rep(TRUE, 5), FALSE)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work: using readr package's parse_number function:

```
library(readr)
mypics <- list(b1.jpg = "b1.jpg", b2.jpg="b2.jpg", b3.jpg="b3.jpg", b4.jpg="b4.jpg", b5.jpg="b5.jpg", b6.jpg="b6.jpg", c1.jpg="c1.jpg",c2.jpg= "c2.jpg",c3.jpg= "c3.jpg", 
               c4.jpg="c4.jpg", c5.jpg="c5.jpg", c6.jpg="c6.jpg", p1.jpg="p1.jpg", p2.jpg="p2.jpg", p3.jpg="p3.jpg", p4.jpg="p4.jpg", p5.jpg="p5.jpg", p6.jpg="p6.jpg")
names(mypics)[parse_number(names(mypics))%%6 !=0]
 [1] "b1.jpg" "b2.jpg" "b3.jpg" "b4.jpg" "b5.jpg" "c1.jpg" "c2.jpg" "c3.jpg" "c4.jpg" "c5.jpg" "p1.jpg" "p2.jpg" "p3.jpg" "p4.jpg" "p5.jpg"
```

Comment: thanks @Karthik S, it's much better than writing loops.